# Angular - Ionic Consumo de Web Service

Tags: angular, typescript, webservice, ionic, undefined

tengo una duda con respecto a un consumo de un ws, cuando lo pruebo en postman me muestra el JSON que me va a regresar, cuando lo consumo en mi pagina y guardo lo que me devuelve y al correr lo en un dispositivo o con ionic serve me marca un error de que no se puede leer nada porque es undefined. Lo intento consumir en el ngOnInit o desde el constructor pero me sigue marcando que es null, no sé si es porque no lo consume a tiempo o quien sabe, agradecería mucho la ayuda.

```
constructor(
    private direccionesService: DireccionesService,
    private platform: Platform
) { }

async ngOnInit() {
    await this.platform.ready().then(
      () => {
        this.direccionesService.getDirecciones().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.direcciones = data.data.direcciones_entregas;
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de Postman:

```
{
    "title": "¡Bien!",
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Datos obtenidos",
    "data": {
        "direcciones_entregas": [
            {
                "id_direccion_entrega": 1,
                "s_alias_direccion": "direccion prueba",
                "s_calle": "calle 1",
                "s_exterior": "10",
                "s_interior": "02",
                "s_codigo_postal": "6800",
                "id_colonia": 3,
                "id_municipio": 1,
                "id_estado_republica": 9,
                "n_latitud": 0,
                "n_longitud": 0,
                "id_usuario_solicita": 1,
                "s_comentario": "dasdasad",
                "b_activo": 0,
                "municipio": {
                    "id_municipio": 1,
                    "s_nombre": "Acambay de Ruíz Castañedas",
                    "id_estado_republica": 15,
                    "b_activo": 1,
                    "b_delegacion": 0
                },
                "estado_republica": {
                    "id_estado_republica": 9,
                    "s_nombre": "Ciudad de México",
                    "b_activo": 1
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo del json que devuelve la API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar en un `console.log()` que respuesta obtienes del ws, y podrias verificar si tienes los datos que esperas

```
   ngOnInit() {
       this.direccionesService.getDirecciones().subscribe(
              data => {
                console.log(data);
              });
          
      }
```